# Is it better to install software through software center or compile it myself?

Tags: software-installation, software-center

This is kind of a general question about installing stuff and remove as well. I've never compiled any software from source but I'm wondering, is it better? What are the pros and cons of each ways of installing software.

By the way, I'm currently using Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: The answers don't really address this, but your question suggests that when you say "command line" you are implying compiling from source, rather than `apt-get`. Is that correct?

Comment: The word `better` creates opinion based answers.Asking for specific comparison which can be verified would be better suited on AU.

Comment: yeah this was a general question and maybe this wasn't the place to ask it, sorry for that.
for example, some software are not at the same version whether you look in the software center and on the website of the software. in some forums, you will see people saying that you should get it from the website instead of the software center. likewise, some people will say to compile it yourself. so my question was: where can I find a discussion about everything involved in the process of installing something new...

Comment: **Ubuntu forums** would be the best place for this discussion.

Answer (score 3):

## Manual compilation

## pros:

- if you are developer, you can change anything you want and implement new features in the software

## cons:

- You *shold be developer*, that's not easy.
- And you should well understand alien code and know programming languages
- And you should track your software manually

## Command line

### pros:

- more informative installation process
- shows errors in the case if they appear. You can simply copy them and search solution in the Internet.
- possible to manually remove locks

### cons:

- you should know the exact name of the package
- you should *type commands* and know what are you doing
- you should track self-compiled packages manually

## GUI

### pros:

- You have a big choice of available packages
- Easy to learn
- Shows a lot of information about packages
- Handles all packages automatically

### cons:

- progress is less informative
- in case of errors you should do a screenshot and optionally edit it in graphic editor before posting to forums.
- if some installation left lock inside directories `/var/lib/apt/lists`, `/var/lib/dpkg`, `/var/cache/apt/archives` you should use Terminal
- some software is not accessible and you should search for it in the Internet

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, but in the general use case the Ubuntu Software Center is better because it shows a package description, screenshot(s) if the package is a GUI application, and most importantly it also shows the package's add-ons, if there are any, that can be installed at the same time that you install the package. This feature of the Ubuntu Software Center can save you a lot of time.

In the particular use case where you want to install a long list of packages, I prefer to use the terminal instead of the Ubuntu Software Center, because I can install several packages with one command of the form:

```
sudo apt-get install package1 package2 ... last-package-in-the-list
```